# Getting the src value on a click for a bootsrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the `src` value of an image with JQuery to pass it into a bootstrap modal to display it on. My issue is that I don't how to get this `src` value, I've tried to make some javascript but I guess it doesn't work properly. Any help please.

Here's my image:

```
<img class="img-thumbnail" src="" data-def-dd="pic" id="pic" name="pic">
```

The Boostrap modal:

```
<div id="img_modal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="" data-onload="loadImage()"
                 data-def-dd="photo" id="photo_modal" name="photo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally the javascript:

```
var src = $(this).attr('src');
console.log(src);

function loadImage(){
    $('#photo_modal').attr('src', src);
}
```

Comment: On which event you want to add src to #photo_model? From which Image?

Comment: the scenario is when i will click on a resized image i will load it after in a bootstrap modal but i need first to get the right src value for the clicked image :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get the source of any image you can do:

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
     var imageSource = $(this).attr('src')
})
```

Comment: where did you get the urge to attach the click event to the image?

Comment: Here is a comment that the OP has posted  to your answer. 'Thanks, but it's not exactly what i need, i want to get the right image src when i click on it then i will pass it to the modal'. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Of course I could also attach the click event to the class 'img-thumbnail', As yo can see in my comment I sad 'any image'

Comment: i get the src but the modal don't receive it

Comment: You can follow for this the answer already posted by @Mr Alexander. I could also update my question to do this, but it will be the same as Alexander suggest you, which is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the image `#pic`, its source will be added as the source of the image `#photo_modal`.

```
$('#pic').on('click', function() {
    $('#photo_modal').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eldien/h3g18b92/2/)

**HTML**

```
<img class="thumbnail mini-thumb" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" width="200" data-def-dd="pic" id="pic" name="pic" data-bigpic="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" />

<img class="thumbnail mini-thumb" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" width="200" data-def-dd="pic" id="pic" name="pic" data-bigpic="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" />

<div id="img_modal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="" id="photo_modal" name="photo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- I used data-bigpic so that you can add a small image for your thumbnail and a second larger one for the modal.
- A class was added to reuse the functionality of the jquery function

---

**Javascript(jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadPreviews();

});

function loadPreviews(){
    $(".mini-thumb").on('click', function(){
        console.log("Img url " + $(this).data('bigpic'));
      $("#photo_modal").attr("src", $(this).data('bigpic'));
        $("#img_modal").modal("show");
  });
}
```

- The function gets the data-bigpic value and adds it to the modal image.

--EDIT--
Here is the same [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eldien/quzxdL9o/2/) but using the src from the image.

*This is just my opinion but I believe it might be better to reload the modal content using ajax. If you do this, your page will only need to load the mini-thumbs. Then using the data-bigimage value you load the data your server returns. It might help if you have a lot of images*

Answer (score 1):

Try this, essentially you need to get the source of the img and insert it into the modal's "";

First, you should give an id to the image that you want to get the source from to make it easier to retrieve and also make sure that more than 1 image is not associated with a class.

```
<img id="img-thumbnail" class="img-thumbnail" src="" data-def-dd="pic" id="pic" name="pic">
```

Second, the function should be adjusted as follow:

```
function loadImage(){
    // get the src of the image
    var image_src = $("#img-thumbnail").attr('src');

    // assign it to the modal's body
    $("#photo_modal").attr('src',image_src);
}
```

Second, you can execute this code when the page loads:

Option 1:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   loadImage();
});
```

Option 2:

You can execute the function when the modal is loaded, there may be a lag as it needs to be loaded.

```
$('#img_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    loadImage();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what i need, i want to get the right image src when i click on it then i will pass it to the modal

Comment: Are you able to elaborate please? Also, if you have jFiddle its much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Add for example an input `hidden` identified by `clicked-img-src` and define `click` event to handle the user click on `img` and get the `src` attribute from the clicked image using `.attr('src')` then store in input  :

```
<input type="hidden" id='clicked-img-src'/>

$('body').on('click', 'img', function(){
     var img_source = $(this).attr('src');
     $('#clicked-img-src').val(img_source);
})
```

Then when the `loadImage()` function called in the `onload` get the `src` from the input :

```
function loadImage(){
    $('#photo_modal').attr('src', $('#clicked-img-src').val());
}
```

Hope this helps.